# How to Use GetCORSystemDirectory()?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clr

```
HANDLE Proc;
HMODULE hDLL;
hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("mscoree.dll"));
if(hDLL == NULL)
    cout << "No Dll with Specified Name" << endl;
else
    {

    cout << "DLL Handle" << hDLL << endl<<endl;
    cout << "Getting the process address..." << endl;
    Proc = GetProcAddress(hDLL,"GetRequestedRuntimeVersion");

    if(Proc == NULL)
        {
         FreeLibrary(hDLL);
         cout << "Process load FAILED" << endl;
        }

    else
        {
         cout << "Process address found at: " << Proc << endl << endl;  
         LPWSTR st;DWORD* dwlength; ;DWORD cchBuffer=MAX_PATH;
         HRESULT hr=GetCORSystemDirectory(st,cchBuffer,dwlength);
         if(hr!=NULL)
         {
            printf("%s",hr);
        }
        FreeLibrary(hDLL);
        }
    }
```

i did like this to get the .NET installation path but i am getting Linker Errors.

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GetCORSystemDirectory@12 referenced in function _main    dot.obj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the GetCORSystemDirectory signature:

```
typedef  HRESULT  ( __stdcall *FNPTR_GET_COR_SYS_DIR) ( LPWSTR pbuffer, DWORD cchBuffer, DWORD* dwlength);
```

initialise the function pointer:

```
FNPTR_GET_COR_SYS_DIR   GetCORSystemDirectory = NULL;
```

get a function pointer from mscoree.dll and use:

```
GetCORSystemDirectory = (FNPTR_GET_COR_SYS_DIR) GetProcAddress (hDLL, "GetCORSystemDirectory"); 
if( GetCORSystemDirectory!=NULL)
{
    ...
    //use GetCORSystemDirectory
    ...
}
```

As requested:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT            
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0600     
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

typedef  HRESULT  (__stdcall *FNPTR_GET_COR_SYS_DIR) ( LPWSTR pbuffer, DWORD cchBuffer, DWORD* dwlength);
FNPTR_GET_COR_SYS_DIR   GetCORSystemDirectory = NULL;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("mscoree.dll"));

    GetCORSystemDirectory = (FNPTR_GET_COR_SYS_DIR) GetProcAddress (hDLL, "GetCORSystemDirectory"); 
    if( GetCORSystemDirectory!=NULL)
    {
        TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH];
        DWORD length;
        HRESULT hr = GetCORSystemDirectory(buffer,MAX_PATH,&length);

        // buffer should contain the folder name
        // use it..

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the documentation on GetCORSystemDirectory to understand what it does. Here's a link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0588yw5(VS.71).aspx

Comment: @Cute: Yeap, that's the path where .NET is installed.
@Indeera: Size of buffer should be MAX_PATH + 1 for the sake of trailing zero paranoia and avoiding possible buffer overruns.

Comment: @sharptooth: No need, I'm passing in the size of the buffer.

Comment: Sure, but the code that will deal with the buffer contents afterwards will need to take that length into account too. That's risky. It's much better to make a buffer larger by one and zero it out entirely - the string will become null-terminated automatically.

Comment: sharptooth: ofcourse in production code, but that's an entire evening of discussion :) This is just an illustration.

Comment: How can i print the buffer value.i tried cout<<buffer but it doesnot work

Comment: if you are compiling in Unicode mode use 

wcout << buffer << endl;

Comment: how can i convert it to string or char[]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass "GetCORSystemDirectory" as the second parameter into GetProcAddress() - it will return a pointer to that function implementation. Then you'll cast the pointer appropriately and call the function through it.